# How to use Ghostscript on Debian to view a PS file?

Tags: ghostscript, ps

I am learning to use LaTeX from lshort.pdf.

I am using a Debian 8.3 system with `texlive` package installed.

I am using the Xfce Desktop Environment. X is nalso running.

```
$ ps -ef | grep -E "X|xfce4-session" | grep -v grep
root       615   547  1 Jun03 tty7     00:08:03 /usr/bin/X :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
susam      951   943  0 Jun03 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc
susam     1027   951  0 Jun03 ?        00:00:01 xfce4-session
```

I have this code in foo.tex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Small is beautiful.
\end{document}
```

I compiled it to a PS file with this command.

```
latex foo.tex
dvi foo.dvi
```

Now I want to view the foo.ps generated with Ghostscript because the book mentioned about it.

> Convert the dvi file to PostScript for printing or viewing with GhostScript.

But when I try to view the file using Ghostscript, I get an output like this on the console.

```
$ gs foo.ps
GPL Ghostscript 9.06 (2012-08-08)
Copyright (C) 2012 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
%%BoundingBox: 149 139 308 715
%%HiResBoundingBox: 149.111995 139.301996 307.277991 714.131978
>>showpage, press <return> to continue<<

GS>
```

I tried the `-sDEVICE=display` option too but I got this.

```
$ gs -sDEVICE=display foo.ps
GPL Ghostscript 9.06 (2012-08-08)
Copyright (C) 2012 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
>>showpage, press <return> to continue<<

GS>
```

What is the right way to view how the PS file looks using Ghostscript on a Debian system?

Since a few other Ghostscript commands were suggested in the comments, none of which were present on my Debian 8.3 system, let me provide the set of all commands installed by the ghostscript package on my system.

```
$ dpkg -L ghostscript | grep bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/sbin/update-gsfontmap
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/gs
/usr/bin/ps2pdf13
/usr/bin/ps2pdf12
/usr/bin/ps2pdf
/usr/bin/ps2epsi
/usr/bin/ps2ascii
/usr/bin/printafm
/usr/bin/pphs
/usr/bin/pfbtopfa
/usr/bin/pf2afm
/usr/bin/pdfopt
/usr/bin/pdf2ps
/usr/bin/pdf2dsc
/usr/bin/font2c
/usr/bin/eps2eps
/usr/bin/dvipdf
/usr/bin/gsnd
/usr/bin/gslp
/usr/bin/gslj
/usr/bin/gsdj
/usr/bin/gsbj
/usr/bin/wftopfa
/usr/bin/ps2ps2
/usr/bin/ps2ps
/usr/bin/ps2pdfwr
/usr/bin/ps2pdf14
/usr/bin/gsdj500
/usr/bin/ghostscript
/usr/bin/ps2txt
```

I hope this helps you to help me.

Comment: Don't you have `ghostview`?

Comment: as a beginner step back and do not use `latex` which requires using dvips etc, use `pdflatex` (on the same input file) which will make a pdf file you can view in whatever pdf viewer you have

Comment: @Bernard I don't have `ghostview`. I get
`bash: ghostview: command not found`.

Comment: @LoneLearner it may be called gv but in any case use `pdflatex` these days (the guide you are using was written last century)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sure. I am able to generate PDF file with `pdflatex` but I also want to get used to the traditional way of doing things like the book describes; just so that I know how these things were done before I began working with computers.

Comment: Don't bother with converting it, just view it with evince. At the prompt:  evince <filename.dvi>

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't have `gv` either.

Comment: Use `ps2pdf` to make the PostScript into a PDF then use whatever PDF viewer you usually do

Comment: @LoneLearner you can go back to that once you are familiar with the basics, you probably _never_ need to use the latex-dvips-ghostview toolchain these days, so why worry if it is not set up?

Comment: I have a feeling this might actually be off-topic in the sense that setting up GhostScript on a *nix system isn't actually a TeX issue _per se_: one for the Unix/Linux site?

Comment: They will send him back here because there is a .tex file involved.

Comment: On my Ubuntu system, I have to install `gv` for the viewer part (`ghostscript` itself is just the command-line converter, not the viewer).

Comment: the output you get from `gs foo.ps` is as expected (if you use gs) but it is supposd to have opened another X window showing the output (you are running X ??)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, X is running. I am using the Xfce Desktop Environment (Xfce version 4.10).

Comment: @JosephWright @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the help. Installing `gv` did work. After installing both `gs foo.ps` and `gv foo.ps` although they both commands showed different viewers. I began investigating why `gs` command started working and found that `apt-get install gv` also installed `ghostscript-x` as a dependency. So I uninstalled `gv` and its dependencies, installed `ghostscript-x` only this time and `gs` now worked fine. `ghostscript-x` adds X11 support for `gs` by adding a new device called `x11alpha` as the default device for `gs`.